# ASP.NET Core @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString from View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, session-variables

I am writing an ASP.NET Core MVC 6 app.

In the controller, I am setting a session variable:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("PrimaryNavigation", "First");
```

I access this value from html

```
  @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
    @inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
             var value ='@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("PrimaryNavigation")';
........
        });
    </script>
```

What I need is to change the value of the session, so, the next time the page is rendered, PrimaryNavigation is null

I have tried

```
'@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("PrimaryNavigation","")';
```

But it shows en error under `Session`

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'
```

How can I set a value from Html page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

just because the return type of SetString() method is void and in Razor View,after "@" it requires a value,so you got the error

You could try assign the value of session to another variable and remove the session in "@{}"  Section

For Example，I created a EMpty MVC Project and
in controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("PrimaryNavigation", "First");
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {            
            return View();
        }
```

in Privacy View:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@{
    var v = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("PrimaryNavigation");    
    HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("PrimaryNavigation", "Second");
}


<input id="input"/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {            
            $("#input").val('@v')
        });
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ruikai, I change the value of the session, but when I go to Controller it keeps the first value..

Comment: have you setted the session somewhere else? such as middleware?I got"Second" the second time I got into the controller in my case